# What happens when PHP is inlined in html (or other web files)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I'm new to web development. I've google'd the question and found no result. To begin, consider the following code:

```
<p id="par">Hello World</p>
```

If you have PHP set-up, the following is valid:

```
<p id="par"><?php echo "Hello World";?></p>
```

Both produces the same result, but what I recall is that PHP codes are executed in the server, thus the following question arise concerning the execution of the code:

Is `<p></p>` element first retrieved from server, while some background ajax process waits for the "Hello World"?

I'd really like to know so I can make a more predictable code. Another possible scenario that bothers me is when using javascript and/or jQuery:

```
$(document).load(function(){
   $("#foo").width($("#par").width());
});
```

which raises the question, does it wait for PHP server requests to finnish or does it just load the page therefore, some code that will need to react to the size of the `<p>` element above will be a bug?

Again, pardon the beginner question.

Comment: `$(document).load(function()` means it will load the function once the webpage loads  and it won't bother about PHP Server requests and all

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen So, are you saying, `$("#foo").width($("#par").width())` will not work as expected?

Comment: @JoeyAndres well, if you are new to web development, isn't it time to learn about it? Books, guides, courses? Learning basics will help to eliminate a lot of problems.

Comment: It is not something about it won't work as expected. It is working as expected. Do you want to make it run after php server response ?

Comment: @Regent I am learning about it. That's a bit condescending. I'm asking a basic question that haven't been asked concerning execution flow and you put other people down like that? Why?

Comment: Please don't down-vote perfectly legitimate beginner questions. This is a very reasonable and understandable beginner question. The type of questions a lot of beginners struggled with, myself included.

Comment: @Regent In C++, beginners often wonder, when is a virtual function called, what happens in the instantiation of polymorphic class, i.e, people will want to care about minute details for predictability. I believe, I'm asking an equivalent question here for PHP/HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: @JoeyAndres I do believe that if you would have learned "when PHP code is executed", "how Ajax requests work", "how HTTP works in general" (these all are base things to learn and to understand for web) and "what [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) does", these asked questions wouldn't be questions for you at all.

Comment: @Regent Look, I have a weird approach to this whole trio of language. I was assigned a task to program Business Layer and Database Layer, and for that I used PHP. I didn't once touched any front-end, the front end folks took care of it. Not until recently, I have been learning html/css/js. I have built a server that takes HTTP request using C-code, and that has nothing to do with this question AT ALL. Its like me assuming that you know about SFINAE (Substitution Fail is not an Error) just because you know C++ template. Don't assume too much, not all people took the same approach in learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP it is server side program language. All code will be processed on server before return to client.

I believe in your case JavaScript is client side part. So.
PHP will generate HTML first. Then Browser load HTML(already with "Hello World") and Javascript. And in the end Javascript will get access to `#foo` DOM element.

But here can be case when Javascript loaded before HTML. In this case 
`$("#foo").width($("#par").width())` will do nothing or throw error because no #par element exist yet. To fix this you have to ensure that Javascript start work after all HTML loaded. For this you can use:

```
   $(document).load(function() {
          $("#foo").width($("#par").width())
   });
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok all the time that you type a url in the browser bar and you press enter, your browser is generating a request http to a server.

So eg:

www.example.com/ -> is asking to the example.com server the page index.html which is just text.

When you have something like: 
www.example.com/test.php -> again is just converting all the php in text and returning that text.

You can see this on your Network tab in Firebug for eg.

So PHP is just generating the html code for you straight forward linearly.

**So about your question:**

No it won't be bugged. If you analyse the html code you receive from both you cases, you'll see they are identicall.